# Firebase Realtime Database - "Error: Client is offline". React/NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

Using React with NextJS the following error occurs occasionally when fetching data from a Firebase Realtime Database.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Error: Client is offline.
```

I am using Firebase `9.0.1` for React.

Top Level code for intialisation and config

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import CONFIG from '../CONFIG.json'


const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
  apiKey: CONFIG['FIREBASE_API_KEY'],
  authDomain: CONFIG['FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN'],
  databaseURL: CONFIG['FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL'],
  storageBucket: CONFIG['FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET']

}
const fbApp = initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)
```

And later fetching data

```
export default function Leads() {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const database = getDatabase(fbApp)
    const ads = ref(database, 'ad_results')

    get(ads).then((snap) => {
      const results = snap.val()
      ...
```

I have tried searching similar issues but to no avail, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Joshua, have any of the solutions below helped you? I'm also using nextjs and having the same problem on 9.0, same as you

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with my Cloud Functions, which was very confusing. After some hours of debugging, I found out that the `.get()` method of the Realtime Database was causing this problem. My current workaround is to use instead `.once('value')`.

So I changed my code from:

```
await database.ref(`foo/bar`).get();
```

to

```
await database.ref(`foo/bar`).once('value');
```

Comment: I was getting this error (just started after upgrading to firebase-admin 11.0.0) and tried your solution. It stopped the "Client is offline" error, but instead the cloud function is timing out (after 60 seconds). It was working flawlessly before I upgraded and redeployed. Going to have to dig deeper...

Comment: I rolled back firebase-admin to 10.2.0 (from 11.0.0) and firebase-functions to 3.20.1 (from 3.21.2) and the problem has gone. Obviously something has changed in firebase-admin 11.0.0 to trigger this issue. I'll post an issue about this on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I am using firebase nodejs SDK, also facing the same error: "Error: Error: Client is offline." occasionally.

I have tried the above solution posted by Nils Reichardt. It works for me.

Thanks Nils!